Need help writing data from a simulation in a text file using C
I'm trying to save the data from my simulation, this is what I'm doing;
In each time steps I write the value calculated in a new line, and I repeat this for every simulation (nsim simulations). I want to write the results from every simulation in a new column step by step of the time loop.
I'm programming in C language, I don't know if is possible to this in C or maybe is a better option to save it in other way the data and process it in pyhton or something like that. This a scheme of  the main loop:
for (int m = 0; m < nsim; m++){ // Simulation loop

        f1 = fopen("x.txt", "a");

        if (f1 == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if(m == 0){
            fprintf(f1, "0.00\t%lf\t", x_0);
            fprintf(f1, "\n");
        }

        for(int t = 1; t < timesteps; t++){ // Time loop

            if (m == 0) {
                fprintf(f1, "%.2lf\t", h*t);
            }
    
                " Does all the calculations to get x"

            if (m == 0) {
            fprintf(f1, "%lf\t", x);
            }

            else {
                fprintf(f1, "%lf\t", x);

            }

            fprintf(f1, "\n");

        }

        fprintf(f1, "\n");
        fclose(f1);

        printf("Simulation %d completed\n", m);

    }

In the way that I'm writing the results in a text file I get something like this:

Time    Sim 1   Sim 2   Sim 3       
1.00    0.001000    
2.00    0.001100    
3.00    0.001300    
4.00    0.001900    

0.001200    
0.001100    
0.001300    
0.001800    

0.001200    
0.001200    
0.002100    
0.003100

The last two columns that appear at the end correspond to the Sim 2 and Sim 3, and I want them to appear nest to the other two at the top.

If you are writing those results to a text file, how are you doing it, and what is the problem? Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example, the shortest complete code that shows the problem.

What's your question? What's the problem with that output (other than the fact that there are 4 column headings, but each line has only 1 or 2 values)?

If you want each sim result to be on the same line, you need to swap the order of the nested loops.

And write a space after each sim result, not a newline.

If you can't reorder the loops, then collect the data into a 2d array with the loops as is, then swap the loops to display the results. Change the timestep and it's printf to use double if needed.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
FILE *f1;
int nsim = 3;
int timesteps = 4;
double *simtimes;

double simt[3][4] = {{.001100, .001200, .001800, .001900}    /* fake times */
                 ,{.001200, .001400, .001600, .001700}
                 ,{.001400, .001500, .001700, .001800}};

    simtimes = malloc(nsim * timesteps * sizeof(double));

    f1 = fopen("x.txt", "a");
    if (f1 == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < nsim; m++) {          // Simulation loop
        for (int t = 1; t < timesteps; t++) { // Time loop
            simtimes[m*timesteps+t-1] = simt[m][t-1];
        } 
    }
    for (int t = 1; t < timesteps; t++) {     // output results
        fprintf(f1, "%04d", t);
        for (int m = 0; m < nsim; m++) {
            fprintf(f1, " %0.6lf", simtimes[m*timesteps+t-1]);
        }
        fprintf(f1, "\n");
    }

    fprintf(f1, "\n");
    fclose(f1);
    free(simtimes);
    return 0;
}


You have the order of the nested loops wrong. The outer loop needs to be timestamps, the inner loop should be sims.
The basic structure should be:
for (int t = 0; t < timesteps, t++) {
    fprintf(output_file, "%d ", t);
    for (int i = 0; i < nsim; i++) {
        // calculate result
        // ...
        fprintf(output_file, "%.6f ", result);
    }
    pfrintf(output_file, "\n");
}


Try to make sure the time column is written once at the beginning, followed by simulation results in separate columns.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    ....

    int nsim = 3;
    int timesteps = 5;
    double h = 1.0;       // Time step size

    FILE *f1;

    f1 = fopen("x.txt", "w");

    if (f1 == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Write the header for the time column and each simulation
    fprintf(f1, "Time\t");
    for (int m = 1; m <= nsim; m++) {
        fprintf(f1, "Sim %d\t", m);
    }
    fprintf(f1, "\n");

    // Time loop
    for (int t = 1; t < timesteps; t++) {
        // Write the current time step value
        fprintf(f1, "%.2lf\t", h * t);

        // Simulation loop
        for (int m = 0; m < nsim; m++) {
            // " Does all the calculations to get x"

            fprintf(f1, "%lf\t", x);
        }

        fprintf(f1, "\n");
    }

    fclose(f1);

    return 0;
}

